# C++ Ifstream into an array of class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, ifstream

I'm having some trouble with a programming project. I want to get information from a .txt document, and store the information in an array of class objects. For each line of the .txt document, I want a new class object to be created.

So if there was

"10 Mark 9/24/1988 accounts manager

9 Jenny 8/6/1983 shipping assistant"

in the .txt, the first line would be stored in the variables of the first object at uArray[0] and the second line would be stored in the variables of uArray[1].

I've created a class "users" with five variables.

```
int iD;
string name, birth, sSN, dept, position;
```

This is what I have, I know it is way, way off, but I can't get it right..

```
{
ifstream myFile;
users uArray[100];

myFile.open("users.txt")
while(!myFile.eof())
   {
   myFile >> uArray.users.iD >> uArray.users.name >> uArray.users.sSN ...(ect);
   }
}
```

Should I create a function to call that will sort the information or is there an easier way? I'm stuck... Sorry for the beginner's questions...

Comment: One obvious error is the `while` loop. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for more on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload the `operator>>` to make this a little easier. This is the actual purpose behind operator overloading. You provide a custom behavior and it is completely transparent when using streams. Declare a `friend`-function inside your class

```
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, users& user);
```

and implement it

```
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& stream, users& user){
    stream >> user.iD >> user.name >> user.sSN ...(ect)
    return stream;
}
```

You can then use a for-loop and do as you did above. But you must use array-indices to address single elements within the array

```
int i = 0;
while(!myFile.eof())
{
    myFile >> uArray[i].users.iD >> uArray[i].users.name >> 
    uArray[i].users.sSN ...(ect);
    i++;
}
```

See [here](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson25.htm) for a tutorial.

Comment: There's no need to make it a friend function, provided the access to the members is public. If you declare it as a friend function though, that declaration must be inside the class and not on its own (at namespace scope).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but if you read my post thoroughly, I stated that it must be declared inside the class.

Comment: True, I overlooked that, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Don't use `while (!file.eof())`. Use `while (file >> content >>> ...)`

Comment: Okay, why that? I am just curious

Comment: Thank you all so much, this came in while I was sleeping. Back up, to work on it some more.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more akin to this, where you are indexing into the array:

```
ifstream myFile;
users uArray[100];

myFile.open("users.txt")
i=0;
while(!myFile.eof())
{
    myFile >> uArray[i].iD >> uArray[i].name >> uArray[i].sSN ...(ect);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the elements of `uArray` correctly.  Since it's an array (of size 100 in your example), you need to specify which array element you want to load data into, as in

```
uArray[i].users.iD
```

One solution to your problem is to have a variable that's incremented for every record in your file:

```
int index = 0;
while ( !myFile.eof() && index < 100 ) {
    myFile >> uArray[index].users.iD >> ...;
    index++;
}
```

BTW, you'll get extra points if you give the "100" value a name (either as a `#define` or as a `const int`), and use that value to compare `index` against.